# Find out whether a Process is a System Process

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to find out what programs a user is running while my program is running and output them to a file. Now I'm facing the situation that when retrieving all Processes using `Process.GetProcesses()` I'm greeted with a list of about 269 processes which amounts to about all the Task Manager is showing, including Windows Processes like 77 svchost processes.

Now I want to filter out some system processes (At least those displayed as "Windows-Processes" in the Task Manager). Is there any way to do this or will I have to maintain a list of process names (or file directories) of all Windows Processes?

Comment: As I had nothing better to do (if that just had been the case - the truth is, I could not stop investigating :D) I investigated your question and came up with a rather disappointing result - have fun reading it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The solution within the taskmanager is hard coded based on the following list (taken from the Windows 10 version):

```
%windir%\explorer.exe
%windir%\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
%windir%\system32\WerFault.exe
%windir%\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe
%windir%\system32\backgroundTransferHost.exe
%windir%\system32\winlogon.exe
%windir%\system32\wininit.exe
%windir%\system32\csrss.exe
%windir%\system32\lsass.exe
%windir%\system32\smss.exe
%windir%\system32\services.exe
%windir%\system32\taskeng.exe
%windir%\system32\taskhost.exe
%windir%\system32\dwm.exe
%windir%\system32\conhost.exe
%windir%\system32\svchost.exe
%windir%\system32\sihost.exe
```

**Long answer:**

It took some time to get to that list - below is the path to enlightenment ;-)


**Original answer:**

To answer your question *Find out whether a Process is a System Process* is not as easy as it seems. In order to get this information you have to get the *owner* of the process which on windows systems is typically realted to [Security identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/security-identifiers).

> A security identifier (SID) is a unique value of variable length used to identify a trustee. Each account has a unique SID issued by an authority, such as a Windows domain controller, and stored in a security database. Each time a user logs on, the system retrieves the SID for that user from the database and places it in the access token for that user. The system uses the SID in the access token to identify the user in all subsequent interactions with Windows security. When a SID has been used as the unique identifier for a user or group, it cannot ever be used again to identify another user or group.

You will have seen one of those for sure, it is something like *S-1-5-18* or *S-1-5-21-2557247...-...-...-1001*.

There is a complete list of [*WellKnown SIDs*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/well-known-sids) which also includes a bunch of SIDs you would probably all consider as *System Process*-related.

If I am right in my assumption, you want to get all processes that are running under the *local system account* which would be *S-1-5-18*.

Stop talking, let's code:

First of all we (which is you, I have already tested it ;-) ) need to import [GetSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getsecurityinfo) from *advapi32.dll* like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint GetSecurityInfo(IntPtr handle,
                                           SE_OBJECT_TYPE objectType,
                                           SECURITY_INFORMATION securityInfo,
                                           out IntPtr sidOwner,
                                           out IntPtr sidGroup,
                                           out IntPtr dacl,
                                           out IntPtr sacl,
                                           out IntPtr securityDescriptor);
```

...which requires two enumerations for [SE_OBJECT_TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/accctrl/ne-accctrl-_se_object_type) and [SECURITY_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthZ/security-information) to be defined like this:

```
private enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
{
    SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE,
    SE_FILE_OBJECT,
    SE_SERVICE,
    SE_PRINTER,
    SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
    SE_LMSHARE,
    SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
    SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
    SE_DS_OBJECT,
    SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
    SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
    SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
    SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY
}

private enum SECURITY_INFORMATION
{
    OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 1,
    GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 2,
    DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 4,
    SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 8,
}
```

Now we are almost there. If you call `GetSecurityInfo` in the following manner...

```
uint returnValue = GetSecurityInfo(process.Handle,
                                   SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
                                   SECURITY_INFORMATION.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                   out IntPtr ownerSid,
                                   out IntPtr groupSid,
                                   out IntPtr dacl,
                                   out IntPtr sacl,
                                   out IntPtr securityDescriptor);
```

... and get [ERROR_SUCESS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) as a result (which is `0`), you can use an instance of the [SecurityIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class to check whether the retrieved SID is the local system account or not, like this:

```
SecurityIdentifier securityIdentifier = new SecurityIdentifier(ownerSid);

if (securityIdentifier.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid))
{
    // The process is running unter the local system account.
}
```

That's it.
To achieve the final result you will have to check for multiple SIDs like *System*, *Local service*, *Network service* and so on...

Here is a small example, that does this for all processes on the local machine.
You will need to run this with the right priviledges of course, otherwise you will get access denied errors.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const uint ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        try
        {
            uint returnValue = GetSecurityInfo(process.Handle,
                                               SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
                                               SECURITY_INFORMATION.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                               out IntPtr ownerSid,
                                               out IntPtr groupSid,
                                               out IntPtr dacl,
                                               out IntPtr sacl,
                                               out IntPtr securityDescriptor);

            if (returnValue != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                // If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
                // If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in WinError.h.
                continue;
            }

            SecurityIdentifier securityIdentifier = new SecurityIdentifier(ownerSid);
            Console.WriteLine("Owner of process {0} is {1}", process.ProcessName, securityIdentifier);

            if (securityIdentifier.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Running under System Account");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to retrieve owner for process {0}: {1}", process.ProcessName, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

If you compare the result (of the original answer) with the list of processes in the task manager, there is still a discrepancy. As I investigated this issue further, I came accross an [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606) that states, that processes which are marked as *critical*, will be shown under *windows processes*.

> If the process has a visible window, then Task Manager calls it an "App".
>
> **If the process is marked as critical, then Task Manager calls it a "Windows Process".**
>
> Otherwise, Task Manager calls it a "Background Process".

This can be evaluated by simply calling [IsProcessCritical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-isprocesscritical). Therefore an `DllImport` is needed...

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool IsProcessCritical(IntPtr hProcess, ref bool Critical);
```

...afterwards it can be called like this:

```
bool criticalProcess = false;

if (!IsProcessCritical(process.Handle, ref criticalProcess))
{
    // Could not retrieve process information
}

if (criticalProcess)
{
    // This is a critical process, it should be listed
    // in the "Windows processes" section.
}
```

**Although this sounds promising, it is not - it still leads to incorrect results.**

So after installing [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) (which is an incredible piece of software by the way) and filtering and searching through more than 5 millions of (already pre-filtered) api calls, I noticed, that *Taskmgr.exe* calls [ExpandEnvironmentString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265(v=vs.85).aspx) multiple times with arguments, that are seemingly not retrieved prior to the calls.

After further investigation (and logical conclusion) I noticed, that there is a hard coded list embedded within *Taskmgr.exe*. It can be simply found by using the [Process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer):

1. Starting the process explorer
2. Right-click on *Taskmgr.exe*
3. Navigating to the *strings* tab
4. Scrolling down
5. Being disappointed

There are the following entries:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe
%windir%\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
%windir%\system32\WerFault.exe
%windir%\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe
%windir%\system32\backgroundTransferHost.exe
%windir%\system32\winlogon.exe
%windir%\system32\wininit.exe
%windir%\system32\csrss.exe
%windir%\system32\lsass.exe
%windir%\system32\smss.exe
%windir%\system32\services.exe
%windir%\system32\taskeng.exe
%windir%\system32\taskhost.exe
%windir%\system32\dwm.exe
%windir%\system32\conhost.exe
%windir%\system32\svchost.exe
%windir%\system32\sihost.exe
```

So my conclusion is:
The solution within the taskmanager is hard coded based on the above list (taken from the Windows 10 version).

Comment: Those are some very interesting insights (And wow, the Task Manager's solution is janky...). Thanks a lot for taking so much time to look that up!

Comment: @LW001, you are very welcome - I found it to be really interesting and in addition a really good questions too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by filtering out all processes whose path starts with the path of the windows directory.

You can get the path of the windows directory by calling [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx) 
 with [`Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) like so:

```
var windowsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
```

And then you can filter out all processes whose image is located somewhere in that folder:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var process in processes) {
  if (!process.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(windowsPath)) {
    // Do something with process
  }
}
```

Comment: I had actually considered that and would have probably ended up using that, but can't someone just put their stuff into one of the Windows folders and bypass it? (Also I'd never have come up with `Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows` so thanks a lot for making my life this much easier)

Comment: Yes, processes that run with elevated permissions (Run as admin) can modify and add files in the Windows directory. Actually, most drivers do this.

I currently don't have time to write a proper answer for this, but what you could also try is read the code signing certificate of the executable. Almost all Windows executables are signed using Microsoft's certificate. Other executables can't fake such a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the result:

```
Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
```

Checking the path, could be bypassed

Comment: Although this would be a nice and easy to use solution, it won't end up with the correct result ;-)